# how to check MIME type without hardcoded string

Tags: javascript, fetch, blob, mime-types

I fetch the file via `fetch` api.

I finally get something like this:

```js
const result = response.blob()
```

currently, `result.type` returns `image/jpeg`. What I need to do is check if the file returned is a directory or image or text file.

One way is to do this:

```js
if(result.type.includes('image')){

}
```

I am wondering if there's any other way without hardcoding `image` string like the above.

Comment: Are you looking for a method like blob.isImage or something?

Comment: Is this in a browser, i.e. you're looking for a constant or a mime type parser built-in to the fetch API or the browser? If it was node I'd guess there'd be other libraries you can load that would parse the string for you and give you simple properties to test, but that's probably not worth including otherwise.

Comment: `blob.isImage` would be great. blob.isDirectory would be great. some wrapper which makes it easier so i don't have to write hardcoded strings myself

Comment: yes, it's in a browser, but can use node too as i am using the webpack and react

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mime types never change over time but will be extended, so it's not bad to hard code needed mime types, by the way you can check for image like below,
for images it must start with "image":

```
result.type.startsWith("image/")
```

and for text:

```
result.type.startsWith("text/")
```

for other types, for example:

```
let others= ["video/mp4",...]
if(others.indexOf(result.type)>-1)
```